# Is there an easy way to use more than one private ssh key on the same gitolite client?

Tags: ssh, gitolite

I have a machine running gitolite that is used both for code repos and for Sparkleshare. The problem is that Sparkleshare creates it's own key pair; that key pair authenticates first, and has no permissions on the code repos, so gitolite terminates without trying any other pairs.

I'm thinking that I may need to figure out how to either tell Sparkleshare to use my original key, or write an alias that forces gitolite to use the correct private key--something I'm not sure is even possible.

Comment: If someone with enough rep sees fit, it would be nice to add a sparkleshare tag =)

Comment: Have you tried adding the public SSH key to the relevant `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys` file, following the same pattern as the other key you are using?

Comment: The key is there--it works as long as the other one _isn't_ there.

Comment: Both should be able to coexist in the `authorized_keys` file.  Check your syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never having used [SparkleShare](http://sparkleshare.org/), I am not quite sure of its requirements, but I read some of the documentation to try to get a feel for how it interacts with Git. It looks like it is designed to publish and pull data through a Git repository (it describes using “your own server”, Github, and Gitorious for data storage/transfer/sync/whatever).

In the following I am assuming that you want to serve both your SparkleShare repository and other non-SparkleShare repositories through the same Gitolite installation (so that you can use Gitolite to control access to both kinds of repositories).

It seems to me that it will probably work just fine with a Gitolite-hosted repository if you follow Gitolite’s rules for giving access instead of the generic “Git over SSH” that is described in SparkeShare’s “use your own server” documentation.

In particular, do not use `ssh-copy-id`, or `cat keyfile >> .ssh/authorized_keys` to install public keys into the Gitolite user’s `.ssh/authorized_keys`. This effectively gives the owners of those public keys “administrative access” to the Gitolite installation (e.g. the ability to completely delete the Gitolite installation and anything else stored under that account). Instead, you should [add users through Gitolite](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/doc/2-admin.html#_adding_users_and_repos) to grant new SparkeShare users access to a Gitolite-hosted repository (make and push changes in your `gitolite_admin` clone: put the user’s public key into `keydir/newusername.pub` and add `newusername` to the repository’s access lists in `conf/gitolite.conf`). You can even have [multiple SSH keys associated with a single Gitolite user](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/doc/3-faq-tips-etc.html#_one_user_many_keys) if you think that is the way to go.

---

If you find that you absolutely must still have users with both “full access” keys (no `command=`) and Gitolite-managed keys (keys with `command=`, managed through `keydir/` in the Gitolite admin repository) in the same account’s `.ssh/authorized_keys`, then you may find that you can force *ssh* clients to supply only certain specified keys via the `IdentitiesOnly` parameter (see [*ssh_config(5)*](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5)).

Assuming that you can access Gitolite through Git URLs like `git@server.example.com:projectA.git`, then configure each client like this:

```
Host sparkleshare
    User git
    HostName server.example.com
    IdentityFile ~/sparkelshare/pub_key
    IdentitiesOnly yes

Host gitolite
    User git
    HostName server.example.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa  # or the user's normal, non-SparkleShare key
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

In SparkleShare, set “my own server” to `sparkleshare` (or `git@sparkleshare` if it demands a user part) and set the “folder name” to `our-sparkleshare.git` (whatever the “Gitolite path” to the repository is, not the “full server site path” since access will be going though Gitolite and it expects paths relative to its REPO_BASE setting).

For non-SparkleShare access, use Git URLs like `gitolite:projectA.git`

Comment: I really appreciate all the hard work you put into this, but it doesn't address any of my question. I know how to run sparkleshare, and I have had gitolite running for ages. The issue is having two client ssh keys and selecting between them based on when/why I'm contacting the gitolite server.

Comment: Have you tried `IdentitiesOnly` (though I accidentally left out the value in the example in my original post)? It does exactly what you have asked for: lets you specify exactly which key will be presented to the server by the client. Also, since there may not be a large number of people with knowledge of both SparkleShare and Gitolite, it would help if you could better describe your setup and some details of how each tool works for those that are only familiar with one of them.

Comment: That's the ticket--so I need to set up an alias in my hosts file, and then base the key use off of my host name. Perfect--thanks!